# How to use angularjs directive into directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive.This directive handles drag and drop of child element. The list of the child elements will be generated by the directive from an given array of data. To render each Element I'd like to give the directive a render. At this time I use a fiter. But I think that is not a job for a filter. Is there a way to use an other directive for it?

directive:

```
module.directive('dndSortable', ['$filter', '$log',
function ($filter, $log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            dndValues: '=',
            dndRenderFilter: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            angular.forEach(dndValues, function(value){
                //my first idea was to use a fiter this will create a element
                //but I think thats not the function of fiters 
                //maybe there is a way to use a directive here
                var dndElement = $filter(scope.dndRenderFilter)(value);
                // ... add event handling for dnd to the dndElement
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

filter:

```
module.filter('mySortListRenderFilter', function () {
    return function (imageValue) {
        var img,
            prefix = 'http://prefix/url'; 
        if (!angular.isUndefined(imageValue) || !imageValue.hasOwnProperty('scr')) {
            img = angular.element('<img>');
            img.attr('src', prefix + imageValue.src);
            img.addClass('teaser-gallery-image');
        }
        return img;

    };
});
```

html:

```
<div 
    dndSortable 
    dnd-values="mySortableList" 
    dnd-render-filter="mySortListRenderFilter">
</div>
```

Comment: Please give me your mySortableList and mySortListRenderFilter

Comment: Isolated scope is use only for component base directive. here you can use attrs.dndValues and attrs.dndRenderFilter

Comment: @Shohel in my controller: $scope.mySortableList = [{src:'img1.png'}, {src:imgXYZ.png}]

Comment: @Shohel the code for mySortListRenderFilter you can find in my question.